# Code not entering if statement with valid statement and not exiting while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to see if the Collatz Conjecture is really true, it says that every integer number which is divided per 2 if it's even and multiplied by 3 and added 1 if it's odd, will eventually come to a loop of 4, 2, 1. But it gets stuck in a while loop and doesn't break or gets inside the if statement that I want

```
integers = [5]

#Returns true if a number is even and false if it's odd
def even(num):
    if (num % 2 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
#Returns true if a list of a number is in a loop
def loop(numbers):
    for x in numbers:
        if (numbers.count(x) > 1 or 4 in x == True):
            return True
            break
        else:
            return False
            continue

#Print a list of numbers that agree with the Collatz conjecture
def collatz(list):
    for x in list:

        collatz_nums = []
        l = loop(collatz_nums)
        list.append(list[-1] + 1)

        #Add the first number to the "collatz_nums" list
        if (even(x) == True):
            collatz_nums.append(x / 2)
        elif (even(x) == False):
            collatz_nums.append(x * 3 + 1)

        #Adds numbers to the collatz_nums variable
        while (l != True):
            print("Start")
            if (l == False):
                if (even(collatz_nums[-1]) == True):
                    collatz_nums.append(collatz_nums[-1] / 2)
                    print("/2")
                else:
                    collatz_nums.append(collatz_nums[-1] * 3 + 1)
                    print("*3+1")
            else:
                print("Exit")
                break


    print(F'{x} = {collatz_nums}')

collatz(integers)
```

Comment: You can also just use `while not l`

Comment: `4 in x == True`? You'll need a very strange `x` for that to be true.

Comment: `(4 in x) == True` would be, well, not fine, but correct. Python has an interesting notion of comparison chaining where `in` and `==` are both comparison operators, so without parentheses it's interpreted as `4 in x and x == True`. (The intent was to allow writing things like `3 < x < 7`, like in mathematics. I'm not sure why `in`, `is`, and their negative variants had to be included in this group.)

Comment: But comparisons to Boolean literals is virtually never needed. The result *is* a boolean, so you could have used the original Boolean (or its negation) instead. `(4 in x) == True` is equivalent to `4 in x` alone.

Comment: Since we know the conjecture holds for all numbers up to 2^68 ≈ 2.95×10^20, it might be more effective to print the numbers for which the conjecture doesn't hold, if any ;)

Answer (score -1):

Let's start here

```
collatz_nums = []
l = loop(collatz_nums)
```

You're passing an empty list to a function with only return statements in the event that you have data to loop over, so the function returns, setting `l = None`

Now `while (None!=True)` is an infinite loop since you're never modifiying value of `l`

Perhaps you should move the "add first number" if statements (which really only need to call even function once using if-else) above those two lines? Or above `for x in list` so that you only add the first number once?

I'd also recommend removing `4 in x == True` since I doubt that does what you want

Comment: How is it an infinite loop? Won't it immediately go into the `else` and `break`?

Comment: If that's the case, then OP description doesn't match the code

Comment: With 132k you should know better than to believe people's descriptions :-)